# ExpressJS 4.15.2 Custom Middleware Set Content Type

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I have a tiny piece of custom middleware, but I cannot seem to get the content-type for the response to be anything but text/html.

```
  getValidator: function(req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    if (!req.query.Name) { next('please provide a Name'); }

    return next();
  }
```

This is a super small app with no other pieces of custom middleware.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to answer myself. :) Please correct me if I am incorrect, but this does appear to be working.

```
  getValidator: function(req, res, next) {

    if (!req.query.Name) { return res.status(500).json({ error: 'please provide a Name' }); }

    return next();
  }
```

If you do not use "return" it will keep going through the chain. If you use next('ANYTHING') it will hit ExpressJS's default 404 handler and attempt to return you text/html. I hope this helps somebody! (or me next time I mess it up)

Comment: You could also use `return next('ANYTHING')`. The main issue is to stop the rest of the middleware from being executed by returning from it.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks robertklep!